# Problem in resque: job not getting removed from queue when finished processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, resque

I am using resque, and resque-scheduler in my rails application. I am facing strange problem in using resque-scheduler. One of my job is not getting removed from queue, once it finishes with the 'perform' method. I need to kill it explicitly to get out of the queue, then other jobs in the queue starts executing.

Job class is simple, like:

```
                    class FooJob
                      @queue = :high_volume

                      def self.perform
                        puts "FooJob#perform:"
                        # some method call
                      end
                    end
```

And resque_schedule.yml contains:

```
                    add_jobs_from_foo:
                      cron: "15 * * * *"
                      class: FooJob
                      description: "enqueue jobs from Foo"
```

Can it be problem with gem versions? or any other?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually verify by looking at redis directly?  The job gets removed from the queue before `perform` even starts execution.

Comment: I do not have access to server, so I can't check redis logs. Job executes `perform` method, still stuck in the queue, and next jobs remain in waiting state.

Comment: I didn't mean check the logs.  I meant access redis directly.  E.g., using `Resque.redis.llen('queue:high_volume')`.

Answer (score 0):

lets try this gem "resque-status"

get job status-

```
status = Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id)
```

Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id) object gonna returns:

```
status.pct_complete #=> 0
status.status #=> 'queued'
status.queued? #=> true
status.working? #=> false
status.time #=> Time object        
status.message #=> "Created at ..."
```

get this gem and for details: https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status