# Do I need to clear out my Resque 'processed' queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I'm using `Resque` (and redis) to manage sending notification emails for my Rails 3 app.

I'm using `Whenever` crontab gem to enqueue a job every 30 minutes to check if a notification needs to be sent.

I notice in the `resque-web` interface that there is a 'processed' job each time it completes successfully. Even if i restart redis and also my server, it seems this 'finished' queue doesn't ever clear out. This in itself doesn't bother me, but I want to make sure I'm not supposed to clear it out or something, somehow. Are all these completed jobs just sitting in Redis eating up memory? Will Redis automatically clear them out starting at the oldest when it hits a certain length?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552743/problem-in-resque-job-not-getting-removed-from-queue-when-finished-processing

Answer (score 1):

The processed keys in Redis contain information about how many jobs have been processed by Resque in total, and by different workers.

Once a worker is done processing a job, [`done_working`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L415-421) is called on the worker, which calls [`processed!`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L391-396):

```
def processed!
  Stat << "processed"
  Stat << "processed:#{self}"
end
```

[`Stat`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/stat.rb) is Resque's module to keep track of statistics for an instance of Resque. It only keeps integers, it doesn't store a history of all the jobs completed, just integer counts of things like:

- How many jobs failed in total
- How many jobs failed for a particular worker
- How many jobs have been processed in total
- How many jobs have been processed by a particular worker

You can see this when viewing the source of the module, `<<` simply increments an integer:

```
def <<(stat)
  incr stat
end
```

You shouldn't worry about flushing that. It's very little data proportional to the amount of workers you have. Resque does keep failed jobs around, but that's a good thing and probably not something you should flush.

Comment: So basically you should Resque will delete any finished jobs from Redis? I'm using redistogo so I'm not sure if I have to manually flush the db when it gets full. From what I understand, Resque will only clog up with failed jobs. True?